# When someone praises me awkwardly too much, how to reply?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english

When someone praises me awkwardly, as in too much, to make me happy or to get some help or something else from me, how to say "don't do that".

Like, "**I'll do that for you, you don't need to --- me.**"

What is the word or phrase I can use in that case?

Comment: This is off-topic here, but you might like to register for the [Interpersonal Skills proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many ways, depending upon the situation.

The direct answer would be "You don't need to flatter me."

For a polite rejoinder you could use "Please, you are too kind. I will be glad to help."

If you wish to be humorous you could say "Flattery will get you everywhere."

Answer (score 6):

*Flattery* can be used here, it can be also said like :-

- I will do that for you, this ***sweet-talk*** is not required.
- or sarcastically - "***Butter-up*** and get things done."
- I'll do that for you, without taking your ***blarney*** seriously.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you actually want to say in your reply.

In UK English '*don't mention it*' is a common reply to thanks which is fairly neutral in meaning but depending on tone and context *can* imply '*I did you a favour now shut up about it and leave me alone*'.

If you want to be a bit more explicit you might say something like 'well you caught me on a good day don't expect the same service every time...'

But really this comes down to quite subtle social interactions and your tone, inflection and body language will matte a lot in this sort of situation. even if you suspect that someone is insincere in their tanks or praise it would often be considered a bit aggressive to actually draw attention to it.

Obviously if you are aware of their insincerity it is up to you how you act  on it in future but a simple acknowledgment of thanks is basic politeness. Something like '*You're welcome*' would be polite but noncommittal.

Also bear in mind that they may be embarrassed that they needed help and feel obligated to you or they may genuinely admire you and feel awkward about expressing it so it does you no harm to err on the side of generosity in your response. Also the fact that someone goes out of their way to make you happy is hardly a bad thing unless you know they have an ulterior motive.

Similarly always consider the possibility that spontaneous  praise may be a genuine generous impulse. Somebody thinking '*wow that person is really awesome I wish I could be friends with them*' is not necessarily someting that you want to step on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be such a [kiss-ass](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/kiss-ass?q=kiss%20ass):

> A person who shows an obsequious eagerness to please.

From [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/kiss-ass) (mainly US, offensive):

> To be very nice to people in authority because you want them to help you.

Comment: Note that "kiss-ass" is *quite offensive*. Don't call someone that to their face unless you're trying to be insulting.

Answer (score 0):

If the praise is genuine (not your question), I express gratitude, "Thanks! or "Thank you, I appreciate the kind words." This works well for me because I want everyone to realize that I am a very humble person.

The way I handle the situation you described is with gentle humor.  I don't want to "correct" or make a point that I know that their praise is self-serving so I humorously agree: "You are a great judge of character!", "You are very perspicacious!", or more sarcastically: "How clever of you to notice!".

Then if they follow up by trying to place an onus on me, I have already established a humorous tone and it makes it easier to deal with their imposition using a light touch.